# Knowledgemanagement Software that can be integrated in Microsoft Teams

Tags: windows, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

I'm looking for a Knowledgemanagement software for Windows that can be integrated in Microsoft Teams.
This Software would be used by different kind of people. IT, Sales, HR, Management etc. Some of those people are not really comfortable with IT, so a easy to use tool would be awesome.

What the Software has to offer:

- Integratable in Microsoft Teams (or usable only in MS Teams)
- Available in the German language

What would be super great if it would offer:

- Connection with Microsoft 365 Account, and using those credentials to login to the application

What I would imagine the Software should be like:

- Q & A Style like a forum (e.g Stackexchange) and also Wiki Style
- Able to categorize and tag articles and posts.
- easy to use in terms of inserting pictures (most importantly), maybe even files. something where we could simply copy & paste a picture in would be really cool.
- good search function, so you'll find the stuff you want.
- WYSIWYG editor, markdown only would not be great.

We have tried Stackoverflow for Teams, which was really good, but unfortunately isn't available in German. This unfortunately is a make or break criteria for my management since we have a lot of workers that can't understand english. We have also tried some standard stuff in Teams like the Wiki or just some different channels, however this is just not searchable and manageable enough.

I basically only need a Knowledgemanagement tool, nothing more. So if there was a tool which could do that, but I would have to pay for a lot of additional features that I would not use, that would not be great.

I already played around with PowerApps to create such a knowledgemanagement tool myself, however currently I have no time to really kneel into this and learn PowerApps in depth, since there are to many other projects for me to do.

if it would be open source or free to use that would of course also be great, but is not a make or break criteria.

We're not a really big team, around 30 to 40 people would use this tool.

Is there something like this on the market?